# Is there a way to send an email using c# without setting an smtp server?

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I would like my application's users to be able to use all possible emails. Now if I think about it setting up `if` clauses to track their email provider in order to set an `SmtpServer` and `SmtpServer.Port` would be inefficient. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: by email provider I mean if they are using "gmail.com" or "yahoo.com" or any other mail providers/servers

Comment: Does the app need to be able to read their emails, or just send an email from their address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "track their email provider", but you absolutely *do* need to set an SMTP server to send email - you can't do it otherwise.

If you don't know what their SMTP server is ahead of time (which you won't if it's a desktop application, usually), the easiest thing to do is to provide a settings screen where the user sets their own SMTP information; port, SSL/not, username, password, etc; Then you will use those settings when creating the SMTP connection.

Comment: won't that be a bit hard for the users? especially if they don't know what smtp server to type?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe Actually, my recommendation would be to *not* include random email capabilities in your program at all. There is no need to recreate the email client. But if you absolutely must do so, there's no way around this.

Comment: Oh. Okay at least that question's all cleared out now. Guess I have to make the users know that they only have one or two options on which I could set which server and port to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Configuration dialog to allow them to enter the ip & port?

Perhaps there's some authentication needed, hard to track that too I guess

Answer (score 0):

You can use default mail client setup on computer to send emails. The caveat is that users will need to click 'send' button. Also they would be able to modify email content. This is good for feedback scenarios.

The code may be something like that:

```
Process.Start("mailto:name@company.com?subject=YOUR SUBJECT&body=YOUR EMAIL BODY");
```